# Ingresar Datos en una BD MySQL desde Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Controlador

```
     class RegistroController extends Controller
{
    public function RegistroController(){
        return view('registra');
    }

    public function storeg(Requests $request)
    {
        \App\registro::RegistroController([
            'NombreEmpresa' => $requests['NombreEmpresa'],
            'Ruc'           => $request['Ruc'],
            'DireccionPrincipal' => $request['DireccionPrincipal'],
            'CorreoElectronico' => $request['CorreoElectronico'],
            'PaginaWeb'         => $request['PaginaWeb'],
            'RepresentanteLegal'  => $request['RepresentanteLegal'],
            'Registro'  => $request [date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')],
            'CodIdRep' => $request['CodIdRep'],
            'Telefono' =>  $request['Telefono'],
            'Celular'  =>  $request ['Celular'],
            'Estado'   =>  $request ['Estado'],
        ]);
        return "Empresa Registrada";
    }
}
```

Modelo

```
class registro extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'empresa';

   protected $fillable  = ['NombreEmpresa','Ruc','DireccionPrincipal','CorreoElectronico','PaginaWeb','RepresentanteLegal','Registro','CodIdRep','Telefono','Celular','Estado'];

   protected $PK = 'CodEmpresa';

}
```

Vista

```
<form action="rouete => registra" id="formulario" method="POST" class="smart-form client-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <header>
                                    Registrate GRATIS
                                </header>

                                <fieldset>
                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="NombreEmpresa" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Nombre </b> </label>
                                    </section>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="Ruc" placeholder="RUC">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Ruc</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    <div>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="DireccionPrincipal" placeholder="Direccion" id="Direccion">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Direccion</b> </label>
                                    </section>

                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="CorreoElectronico" placeholder="E-mail">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Correo Electronico</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="PaginaWeb" placeholder="Pagina Web">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Pagina de la Empresa</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="RepresentanteLegal" placeholder="Representante">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Representante Legal</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="DocIdRep" placeholder="DNI del Representante">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Documento del Representante</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="Telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese el Telefono</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <section>
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="Celular" placeholder="Celular">
                                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Ingrese Celular</b> </label>
                                    </section>
                                </fieldset>


                                <footer>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </footer>

                                <div class="message">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                    <p>
                                        <h3>Gracias porRegistrarse</h3>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado para ingresar los datos a la Base de Datos. O en su defecto tus dudas.

Comment: Y cuál es la pregunta o el error?

Comment: puedes poner el código de la ruta y explicar con mayor detalle tu problema o error.

Answer (score 1):

Importante que valides que hiciste importaste las clases necesarias para guardar en la base de datos, entre ella esta Eloquent.

Adicionalmente, la forma de instanciar un nuevo registro el laravel la puedes ver en el siguiente link
[Insertar en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-inserts)

```
<?php     
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;
use App\registro;
 class RegistroController extends Controller
{
    public function RegistroController(){
        return view('registra');
    }

    public function storeg(Requests $request)
    {

        $registro = Registro::create(
        ['NombreEmpresa' => $requests['NombreEmpresa'],
            'Ruc'           => $request['Ruc'],
            'DireccionPrincipal' => $request['DireccionPrincipal'],
            'CorreoElectronico' => $request['CorreoElectronico'],
            'PaginaWeb'         => $request['PaginaWeb'],
            'RepresentanteLegal'  => $request['RepresentanteLegal'],
            'Registro'  => $request [date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')],
            'CodIdRep' => $request['CodIdRep'],
            'Telefono' =>  $request['Telefono'],
            'Celular'  =>  $request ['Celular'],
            'Estado'   =>  $request ['Estado']  
        ]);
        return $registro;
        //Le retorna en JSON el resultado de la insert
        //return "Empresa Registrada";
    }}
```

Ahora, la forma en que estas guardando el registro, al parecer SOLO estas validando el lado del cliente (Y es importante NO confiar 100% en el contenido que envia el usuario.) podrias incluirle reglas de validación 
Puedes ver mas en el siguiente link [Validation en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#validation-quickstart)

Ejemplo:

```
public function storereg(Request $request)
{
    //Reglas de validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'NombreEmpresa' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'DireccionPrincipal' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Si pasa la validacion continuar para insertar el registro
    //Resto del codigo
}
```

espero que esta información se sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

## Problema

Veo que tienes algunos errores en tu función que se encarga de guardar los datos en tu modelo. Primero que nada:

```
$registro = \App\registro::RegistroController([ /* ... */
```

Tu principal problema radica aquí, donde intentas llamar una función estática que no existe en tú modelo. La función correcta es:

```
App\TuModelo::create(/* Los valores deseados para la creación de tu registro */);
```

Sería bueno que agregaras lo que tienes escrito en tu archivo de rutas, para saber cómo estás manejados los **actions** de tus controladores.

---

## Solución

Recordemos que hay múltiples formas para guardar un nuevo registro en **Laravel**. En tu caso, lo podríamos ver de la siguiente manera:

```
public function storeg(Request $request) {

    /**
     * Creamos la instancia de la clase registro
     */
    $registro = new App\registro;

    /* Realizamos la asignación masiva */
    $registro->NombreEmpresa = $requests['NombreEmpresa'];
    $registro->Ruc = $request['Ruc'];
    $registro->DireccionPrincipal = $request['DireccionPrincipal'];
    /**
     * Se repite con los demás datos que desees asignar...
     */

    $registro->save();

    return "Empresa registrada";
}
```

El ejemplo que te muestro es un estilo más orientado a objetos, además de que **Daniel Ferrans** te explicó de manera excelente como usar el método estático `create` en los modelos, no veo la necesidad de nuevo el cómo hacerlo de esa forma.

Saludos.